# Estimating the total number of sample subsets of size 10 from a population of size 1000

Tags: r, sampling, arithmetic, subset

If we have $n > 1000$ units to sample from, how can we estimate the number of subsets of a certain size, since the number is too much for `R` to handle?

What I mean is, if I can't use `choose(1000, 10)` to get the total number of subsets of size $10$, is there a way to estimate it?

Comment: Actually, `choose(1000,10)` works just fine in R for me. If it hadn't, in R I'd just use the `lgamma` function, but more generally, [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) would usually work okay for an approximate answer

Comment: specifically, with the `lgamma` function, `lgamma(n+1)-lgamma(k+1)-lgamma(n-k+1)` will be the natural log of `choose(n,k)`.

Comment: In addition to the answer of @Glen_b (+1): there is also the `lchoose(n,k)` function which calculates the natural logarithm of the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Thanks @CoolSerdash, that's a better function to mention.

Comment: Consider the following function to approximate the log of the factorial, based on Stirling's series to the second term: `stirlog <- function(n) log(sqrt(2*pi*n))+n*log(n)-n+log(1+1/(12*n))`; compare `stirlog(10)` with `lgamma(11)` for example.

Comment: Even back in R2.15 (32bit version) on my machine, multiplying both the above arguments by 10 still works with `choose`. That is `choose(10000,100)` works for me in an older, smaller R.

Comment: It gives you the exponential form in base 10 for the number but not the digits themselves though

Comment: You can change that by specifying the command `options(scipen=999)`. See, for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-r).

Comment: It gives you the first 7 digits of the number itself by default (I assume you understand how scientific notation works). You can get more via the print function (the first 16 or so might still be meaningful; go big and you'll soon be looking at noise though). I am pretty sure having all 241 digits would be of little value but if you need it you should move to high precision calculation. It sounds like you mean to ask a different question than you originally asked.

Comment: If you don't understand how to extract the important digits of the actual number from what `choose(100,10)` gives you, [try here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). Also compare the digits in `choose(100,10)` with the digits in (say) `print(choose(100,10),13)`

Comment: If you can more clearly explain why the output of say `choose(1000,10)` doesn't serve your purposes we might be able to help you further.

Comment: Just in case anyone is confused, the reference to 241 digits above is for the calculation `choose(10000,100)` (though the actual number of digits there if it were written as an integer would be 242). The integer representation for the original `choose(1000,10)` has only 14 digits.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know you could reveal the digits in R, I think my Professor intended to mean if say the number was so huge R would return INF or something as the answer how would one approximate it then. I'll ask him tomorrow if he just wants to know the 31 digits for this particular case I guess. Thanks.